# $f \in \mathbb C[x]$ monic polynomial of prime degree which is not co-prime with any of its derivative polynomials, then $f$ has only one root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, polynomials

Let $f \in \mathbb C[x]$ be a monic polynomial of prime degree $p$ such that $f$ is not co-prime with any $f^{(k)}$ ($k$-th derivative) for $1\le k<p$. Then is it true that $\exists a\in \mathbb C$ such that $f(x)=(x-a)^p$ ?

Comment: For $p=2$, the claim is true because a double root exists if and only if $f$ and $f'$ have a common factor

Comment: @Saun Dev: Nice problem. I think the specification that p is prime can be dropped, given that the ring of coefficients is $\mathbb C$. With some help from Maple, I've proved the claim for p = 2,3,4,5.

Comment: [Related MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27851/polynomials-having-a-common-root-with-their-derivatives)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is a solved particular case of an open problem, called the [Casas-Alvero conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casas-Alvero_conjecture) (from the Spanish mathematician Eduardo Casas-Alvero, proposed in 2001)!

> **Casas-Alvero conjecture.** Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ defined over a field $K$ of characteristic zero. If $f$ has a factor in common with each of its derivatives $f^{(i)}$, $i = 1, \dots, d − 1$ then the conjecture predicts that $f$ must be a power of a linear factor.

Notice that the common factor of $f$ and $f^{(i)}$ (or the common root if $K$ is algebraically closed) may depend on $i$.

But hopefully, the case where $d=p^k$ is a prime power (in particular if $f$ has prime degree) has been solved by Hans-Christian Graf von Bothmer, Oliver Labs, Josef Schicho, Christiaan van de Woestijne
in [*The Casas-Alvero conjecture for infinitely many degrees*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605090v2.pdf), Journal of Algebra 316(1), pp. 224-230 (2007).